# Fork a process inside a bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, ps, background-process

I've a simple shell script like

```
#!/bin/bash

sh -c "sleep 60" &
exec sleep 120
```

In using the `pstree` command, I found something like

```
`-sleep(11681)---sleep(11682)
```

The first sleep is due to the `sh -c`, so even I have execute that sleep in the background, it is now parented at my `exec`'s sleep.

Question: How to detach the first sleep and make the `pstree` have something like

```
 -sleep(11681)
 -sleep(11682)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first sleep is detached already. What's happening is that the `sleep 60` is parented by the shell that is running the script, then the `exec` replaces that shell with the `sleep 120`, so your `sleep 120` is now the parent of your `sleep 60`. To have them at the same level in the `pstree` output, simply background the `sleep 120` just like you do the `sleep 60` instead of `exec`'ing it.

Comment: Keep in mind that as soon as the parent process exits, one or both of your `sleep`s will have a parent of `init` (pid 1), so don't get worried when you don't see them where you expect to in the `pstree` output.

Comment: How about if I want to keep the `exec`? I need the `exec` since this script will be used by `supervisord` as process monitoring. I use `sleep` here as only for the ease of demo only

Comment: If you keep the exec, then your pstree output will remain the same - i.e. the way you don't want it. Sorry, but in this situation I don't see a way you can have your cake and eat it, too.

Answer (score 1):

sleep 60 &
sleep 120 &
wait

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.